# How to configure jenkins to create custom tag?

Tags: jenkins, github

I'm writing Jenkins jobs for my project and trying to automate tag creation.
I'm using Git Publisher plugin in Jenkins for Post-build Actions. This is working fine and gives me a tag whenever I push to the GitHub. But it gives `Default tag` as I was able to configure using inbuilt variable.

```
TAG-$BUILD_ID
```

$BUILD_ID has the default value. But I want to create a custom tag.
eg. Jenkins create `TAG-8` but It should create the tag like this.
`v1.0.0-rc1`

Whenever I commit to the GitHub It should create the incremental tag.

```
Commit      Tag
commit1     v1.0.0-rc1
commit2     v1.0.0-rc2
.....
.....
and so on
```

and the Tags should be created depending upon branches.

```
Branch      Commit        Tag

Branch1             
            commit1       v1.0.0-rc1
            commit2       v1.0.0-rc2
            commit3       v1.0.0-rc3
            ....
            .... and so on

Branch2   
            commit1       v1.1.0-rc1
            commit2       v1.1.0-rc2
            .... 
            .... and so on

Branch3   
            commit1       v1.2.0-rc1
            commit2       v1.2.0-rc2
            .... 
            .... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Version Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin). You should have available all the [environment variables](http://jenkins2.tsl.telus.com/env-vars.html/).  You can use an execute shell step with `set` to see them all.

[image: Formatted version Label option]

Finally, use the label in your tag.
[image]